# Variable in apiResource 404 not found

Tags: laravel, rest

I'm learning `Laravel` and the `apiResource`. My page is returning 404. I need my second path to be a variable because it is to show the sub-categories from the products, so it needs to drill down depending on what ID is passed from the productId.

```
/products - shows the parent products (ie.transport)
/products/{id} - shows (ie.cars)
/products/{id}/{car-types} - shows (ie.sports-cars, luxury-cars, 4wd)
/products/{id}/{car-types}/{id} - shows (ie. the actual car)
```

**Routes**

```
Route::apiResource('/products', ProductController::class);
Route::apiResource('/products.{product-types}', ProductTypeController::class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

**Routes**

```
Route::apiResource('products', ProductController::class)
    ->only(['index', 'show'])
    ->parameters(['products' => 'id']);

Route::apiResource('products.product-types', ProductTypeController::class)
    ->only(['index', 'show'])
    ->parameters([
        'products' => 'pid',
        'product-types' => 'id',
    ]);
```

**URL**

```
/products
/products/{id}
/products/{pid}/product-types
/products/{pid}/product-types/{id}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error here is caused by your use of curly braces (`{`, `}`) in your `apiResource` name parameter, these are not required (check the [#nested resource documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources) for more info).

So to fix your issue, all you need to do is remove the curly braces.

```
Route::apiResource('/products', ProductController::class);
Route::apiResource('/products.product-types', ProductTypeController::class);
```

This will result in standardised routes being produced (use `php artisan route:list` in your terminal to get an output of your available configured routes by the way).

```
GET|HEAD    products ................................................................... products.index › ProductController@index
POST        products ................................................................... products.store › ProductController@store
GET|HEAD    products/{product} ........................................................... products.show › ProductController@show
PUT|PATCH   products/{product} ....................................................... products.update › ProductController@update
DELETE      products/{product} ..................................................... products.destroy › ProductController@destroy
GET|HEAD    products/{product}/product-types ......................... products.product-types.index › ProductTypeController@index
POST        products/{product}/product-types ......................... products.product-types.store › ProductTypeController@store
GET|HEAD    products/{product}/product-types/{product_type} ............ products.product-types.show › ProductTypeController@show
PUT|PATCH   products/{product}/product-types/{product_type} ........ products.product-types.update › ProductTypeController@update
DELETE      products/{product}/product-types/{product_type} ...... products.product-types.destroy › ProductTypeController@destroy
```

**Update**

If your desired route structure is `/products/{category}/{sub_category}/{id}` then the solution would be to not use the `apiResource` helper (as this generates standard/conventional REST URI structures) and instead define the route manually.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/products/{category?}/{sub_category?}/{id?}'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [DemoController::class, 'index']);
    // define other HTTP verb (POST, PATCH, DELETE etc.) routes
});
```

The above makes each of the parameters optional by using the `?` operator.

Then for your `index` (or whatever you want to name it) method:

```
public function index(Request $request, $category = null, $sub_category = null, $id = null)
{
    // do something
}
```

You would need to perform sanity checks on the incoming parameters in order to return the correct data.

Alternatively, you could split the routes into groups and use individual controllers.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/categories'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [CategoryController::class, 'index']);
    
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/{type}'], function () {
        Route::get('/', [ProductTypeController::class, 'show']);

        Route::group(['prefix' => '/{sub_type}'], function () {
            Route::get('/', [ProductTypeController::class, 'show']);

            Route::get('/{id}', [ProductController::class, 'show']);
        });
    });
});
```

The above results in the following route definitions:

```
  GET|HEAD   categories ......................... CategoryController@index
  GET|HEAD   categories/{type} ................ ProductTypeController@show
  GET|HEAD   categories/{type}/{sub_type} ..... ProductTypeController@show
  GET|HEAD   categories/{type}/{sub_type}/{id} .... ProductController@show
```

You should then be able to do things like:

```
/categories
/categories/transport
/categories/transport/cars
/categories/transport/cars/{ID} // ID could be an int or string, up to you
```

Comment: I wanted product types to be a variable

Comment: @ottz0 What do you mean? Product types is a route parameter.

Comment: Instead of product-types, (t-shirts, shoes, jeans) as in products/clothes/t-shirts/id

Comment: @ottz0 So really you want your route definition to be `/products/{category}/{sub_category}/{id}`?

Comment: Yes that's right....Its just that the REST way is index is the collection and show is the singleton and when I pass as {sub_category} I get errors

Comment: @ottz0 I have updated my answer, have a look and try it out.